# Does anyone still bother with IE6 hacks?

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I'm working on a web development project usng PNG transparency, CSS3 and all the other goodies you would come to expect in a "new" web design. IE8 and Firefox look great, IE7 is passable and IE6 looks like the dog coughed it up.

With Windows 7 out in the wild (If you have to dual boot... do it in style :P) and Internet Explorer 6 down to a pitiful 11% market share, has anyone made the decision to ignore it?

Granted, I've still made the effort to make IE6 usable - but how far should I take it (how far have you)? Is anyone else working on a project where they've given the finger to this ancient design massacring nightmare?

browser stats: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, there are still large companies which are limited to IE6 because some ancient internal web app won't work on anything else.

Comment: While we'd all prefer IE6 to go away, the market share stats you link to are **way** off those that I've seen, and what I've seen in the wild.  They've got a little selection bias going on.  Wikipedia's quoted stats match the reality I've seen more closely.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: +1 Michael ... I am pretty sure the w3schools stats are based on visitors to their site only ... not a fair assessment in my eyes.

Comment: +1 Michael -- /everyone/ has selection bias...!

Comment: The only 'reality' to care about for IE6 stats are those of your own site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still try to make my interfaces usable in IE6, but I don't spend the time to make them look perfect, or even decent.  For my projects, it's just not worth the effort.  People and companies with IE6 need to upgrade, period.

Edit: Semi-random addition: I just saw [this graph of web usage](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-weekly-200827-200951) mentioned on Slashdot, which puts IE6 at 14% of all users.  At least it's going down!

Answer (score 4):

I personally tend to try to make my stuff usable even in Lynx. In general, if you start with that in mind, it's pretty easy at least to have it degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be answered by determining the audience for your web site.  If you already have a version of your site running, look at the logs to determine how many people use IE6 and visit your site.  Then you can make the decision on whether you're going to support those users anymore, and whether you're going to make the site work well or just well enough to be usable by those users.

Answer (score 1):

11% is still one in ten users.

Much depends on what you're creating. If you're creating an intranet site where you know that most users should have made it beyond IE6, then go right ahead.

Me, I'd stick with IE6 for the time being for public sites, at least until the percentage drops below 2% or so. But this is really a question for the site owner: are you willing to look ugly for one in ten of your users?

Note, for web design questions of this kind, try [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/). For browser compatibility, try [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/).

Comment: 11% is one in nine, but who's counting.

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Comment: @Chris - my answer is over three years old now, and it's fair to say lots happens in that time, especially in front-end development.

Comment: StackOverflow is alive and thriving :) - Just figured I'd post a note for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's not just a matter of how many people are using IE6, it's a matter of why they're using it.  If 11% of people were using IE6 because they really **liked** IE6 and Ie6 had a chance of gaining popularity as time went on, I'd say they should be considered.  However, given that probably 99% of people using IE6 are using it purely because of inertia and it's getting less popular every day, I don't think it matters too much.  If anything, the fact that your website looks like crap in IE6 will encourage them to upgrade.

That said, I think your page should probably explain to the relatively computer illiterate **why** it looks like crap and that IE6 his a browser from the caveman era and they should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

What does the PNG transparency and CSS3 give you, that can't be done with older technologies?

It might be fun to try the most recent technologies, but you shouldn't throw out one in ten of your customers.

Comment: Transparent PNGs and CSS3 typically give you MUCH more streamlined download. CSS drop shadows, rounded corners, layered transparent PNGs can all allow you to create a page with MUCH fewer image based assets.

Comment: Though that doesn't mean you 'throw out' 10% of your customers. They just wouldn't see quite the polished UI as the rest.

Comment: CSS3 and PNG transparency can make implementing a design significantly easier and are more flexible down the line. There are definitely things that cannot be done without PNG transparency. Examples: http://soulgraffiti.org, http://radialmovement.net/, http://www.wolfire.com/overgrowth

Answer (score 0):

I'm still dealing with IE6.

jQuery has helped.

As has graceful degredation. I use CSS3 now and don't care too much if some things just won't appear in IE6.

For PNGs, Twinhelix has a nice script that does quite a bit for PNG transparency support in IE6:

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Or, alternatively, I use PNG-8s. Not ideal, but really easy.

The only major beef I still have is IE6's lack of double class selectors:

.class1.class2

I could de-bloat my CSS quite a bit of IE6 supported that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been saying this for 3 years now - if you're trying to make things look nice for somebody using IE6, you're wasting your time. People using IE6 are not savvy enough (and depending on what you're doing, are they even your target audience?) to notice or care about the PNG transparency or anything. If they are savvy and they are stuck on IE6 b/c they are at work or something... really, who cares? They probably don't, it's probably just another reason for them to curse their stupid IT department. Not your problem.

Sure, make sure your site WORKS in IE6, but it doesn't have to look nice.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's usually your client who's paying you that is in the 'still using IE6' demographic.

Comment: That is true. One story I hear a lot lately is the boss of his company who demanded that their Flash site was dropped so that he could look at the corporate site on his iPhone. One way to push standards, I guess :)

Comment: @bpapa that's been a great side-effect of the iPhone. We're now seeing iMacs in our IT department as well. I think Mobile has really pushed web standards to the forefront.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I do, as does [Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6557) and [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/).

yes, it sucks, but the numbers are still there (with us it's about 30 - 40% of users still using IE6)

Comment: While google may, google-owned YouTube recently gave up the IE6 support: http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/07/14/youtube-will-be-next-to-kiss-ie6-support-goodbye/

Comment: @Stephen generic stats are useless. All that matters are the stats for your own site.

Comment: yes, also that link you sent is non-sensical, the %s in the data and graph don't line up at all.... http://marketshare.hitslink.com/chartfx62/temp/CFT1220_11314537397.png

Comment: And here's a link that says IE6 is below 14% - http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-weekly-200827-200951

Comment: @Dan - but you can see what they've done can't you.  The pie chart shows the ratio between the top 5 browser/versions, and they've excluded the rest.  But my point is that "30% to 40% of users still using IE6" is unusually high ...

Comment: @DA - what REALLY matters is the trend.

Answer (score 0):

I say join the cause to get IE6 out by choosing not to support it! ^^

But as some others have pointed out, it depends on the target audience, and if you can afford to cut the IE6 users out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of corporate clients, like my company, absolutely yes.  Big companies standardize on a browser and they don't move off it easily.  And often there are enterprise-level systems that depend on a certain browser version, like IE6.

Answer (score -4):

If you design in flash, you'll get cross browser compliance.

Comment: Not if you're using a mobile phone, need a screen-reader, or need your site to be indexed by a search engine. 

Or have any taste. (Sorry, couldn't resist it.)

Comment: And, more often than not, a beast of an unusable web site

Comment: I have to aggree.. Not that flash doesn't have its place, I just don't think its the right tool for an entire website (especially e-commerce etc.)

Comment: You also slow down your users' computers and have content that's pretty useless aside from looking pretty and possibly some copy and paste.

Comment: Why do web devs have this elitist attitude about flash being "beneath" them for some reason?  You CAN index into flash content now, and also deliver a better experience then htmljscss alone.

Comment: I agree with the comments here, the trade off of using flash is a loss of usability.

Comment: "elitist" is not a synonym with "experience". The flash people that usually pull the elitist card don't know anything but flash. Flash is a great technology. Useful for all sorts of web site components. It's usually NOT great for smashing an entire site into, though. As for delivering a 'better experience'...that's entirely dependant on the context of the site and content being delivered.

Comment: Come back to me when you're streaming movies using HTML alone.  Either that or wait for HTML 5 to "save" you.  HTML is a cobbled together mess of hacks built on hacks running in hacks

Comment: @Pierreten you're simply showing your lack of knowledge outside of Flash. You also didn't really read what I said. Flash isn't bad. Using flash for the entirety of your site, often is. It's all about context and using the right tool for the right component. If you think HTML is just a 'cobbled together mess of hacks', that says more about the developers you work with than HTML itself.

Comment: HTML is an utter mess and you know it.